# AnkhSVN over ssh problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I try to use the newest AnkhSVN with svn+ssh, but when I try to add a VS 2010 solution to the repository with URL svn+ssh://some.domain.com/svn/ I get the login window. Then I type the password and I can see the repo.

**BUT** when I click OK everything hangs and window's title says Not Responding.

Please, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you select the correct branch in the repo and not the root directory?